# Ember bind-attr no updating, although controller property updates just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, ember.js, binding

I have a controller that disables a button in the template when the property `isProcessingSubmit` is set to `true`. Or at least it should disable.

The template has the following code:

```
<button type="submit" {{bind-attr disabled=isProcessingSubmit}}>Sign in</button>
```

On the controller, I have this:

```
App.SignInController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isProcessingSubmit: false,

    enableProcessingSubmit: function() {
        this.set('isProcessingSubmit', true);
    },
    disableProcessingSubmit: function() {
        this.set('isProcessingSubmit', false);
    },

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        App.Events.on('ajax.onStart', this.get('enableProcessingSubmit'));
        App.Events.on('ajax.onComplete', this.get('disableProcessingSubmit'));
    },

    ...

});
```

Those events are fired by handlers to the jQuery global ajax events. I confirmed that the events are fired properly, and the `enableProcessingSubmit` and `disableProcessingSubmit` are called as expected.

Also, if I set the `isProcessingSubmit` flag to `true` on the controller right of the bat the button comes up disabled as expected. So basically it is not able to see the change when I do the `set` calls.

What am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to pass the controller as the "this" in the event callbacks:

```
App.Events.on('ajax.onStart', this, this.get('enableProcessingSubmit'));
App.Events.on('ajax.onComplete', this, this.get('disableProcessingSubmit'));
```

It's working now.